# How to find if item already present in the datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to find if the item i want to add is already present in the datagridview or not ?

```
if (dgvIndex >= 1)
{
    foreach (dataGridView1 row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.cells[1].value == dr[1].ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item already added");
        }
    }
}
```

is is correct ?

I am getting an error: datagridview1 is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreach` keyword expects you to say something like:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
```

The `DataGridView` is for specifying the type of the `row` variable.  The compiler is telling you that `dataGridView1` is not a type.

I think you have some other syntax errors to fix, like the casing on `row.cells[1].value`.  In any case, hopefully this gets you a bit closer to compiling.

Comment: yes it did. now "cells" in this line "if (dataGridView1.Rows.cells(1).value == dr[1].ToString())" is showing error. How to solve that, and why its showing ?

Comment: There are several things wrong with that bit of code.  First of all, dataGridView1.Rows will return a collection, not a single row.  You'll need to specify a specific row, like this: `dataGridView1.Rows[someNumber]`.  Next, C# is case sensitive.  `DataGridViewRow` does not have a property named `cells`; it's `Cells` with a capital C.  Next, to get a cell from the list you need to use square brackets rather than parentheses: `Cells[1]` rather than `Cells(1)`.  The error messages in Visual Studio combined with a little googling should be all you need to make sense of syntax errors like these.

Comment: I want o check if the data is already present in the datagridview or not. How should I check that then ?

Comment: I recommend you make the changes necessary to get your code to compile (by googling the error messages), then if it doesn't work as expected, ask a new question for help with the algorithm.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend getting a beginning C# book to learn the basic syntax so you don't make these syntax errors in the first place.  Once you've got the basic syntax, I recommend the MSDN documentation for specific classes.  For instance, to know how to use a `DataGridView`, google "DataGridView class" and follow the top link, which will take you to the MSDN documentation for that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time n help @adv12 :)
Finally I got the answere, here it is:
if (dgvIndex >= 1)
{
foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
if (row.Cells[1].value.ToString() == dr[1].ToString())
MessageBox.Show("Item already added");
}
}